# php, how to send form data in a secure way?

Tags: php, forms, https, secure-coding

i have a website that has a simple login form.

the form posts to `login.php`

inside `login.php` i check for username and password and redirect to a specific page.

All is good until i come across security. From PCI compliance i get this:

> All web application communications containing sensitive information should be transmitted using SSL/TLS (HTTPS). If re-direction from HTTP to HTTPS is utilized in an attempt to remediate this finding, please ensure that such re-direction occurs on the server side of the system (for example via the use of the HTTP "Location" header element) and that re-direction is not reliant upon the client (browser) side.

then i went into `login.php` and added this code at the top:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || !$_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
    header("Location: https://" . $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
}
```

If i try to login after this change the login process seems to go through fine, except im not sure that this solved the problem.

**notes:**
i cant set the website to be: `https://www.website.com` because this will throw a security warning. I do have a valid certificate though.

any ideas how can i fix this issue?

thanks

edit:

the security warning is about accessing an insecure website, the red rectangle asking me if im sure i want to go to this website and i can add it to the exceptions list

if i add the certificate under m the exception list, this alert happens only once

Comment: What's the security warning??

Comment: What does the security warning say?

Comment: Without the warning there is not much to go on here, is the warning that you have insecure information also on the page? Or is it that the SSL certificate is not signed correctly?? or something else. More information would help everyone in assisting you

Comment: @Patrioticcow it sounds like the IE browser warning about an "unknown" or invalid SSL certificate. Who provides the certificate and is it valid for the domain that you are requesting against?

Comment: On the security warning side, you might want to make sure that no dependent files (js, css, images, etc) are being called with absolute urls that are not secure (i.e. they should not start with 'http')

Comment: ok, what about not using that option of setting the website under https, what about other options

Comment: @Patrioticcow What are you trying to protect with SSL?? If it is just the authorisation then you could look at HTTP digest authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your certificate may be valid, but it's not recognized by the browser as safe.  You need to find out why the browser is saying it's not valid.  Usually it's either been generated by a company using a root certificate that the browser doesn't recognize.  You may need to switch certificates to get rid of the "red rectangle."

Comment: i understand what you are saying, but what about not using https for the main index.php? I try to stay away from that for some SEO purposes as well

Comment: You can do that, but I don't know how your compliance department would feel about that. ;)  Even if you don't use it on your index, the moment you want them to log in, your users are still going to face that "error" page.  My advice is that if you feel this cert really should work, talk to your cert provider about reissuing.  If it's a self-issued cert or rinky-dink company, I'd spring for an industry accepted cert like Verisign, Thawte, etc

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your pages aren't including something via http transport, like a jpg or embedded object. You can tell the browser to use https for the page but if the page calls jpgs or other scripts or something, you're able to call those with http. The browser then thinks the page has secure and insecure objects and that can be an issue.